# Return click functionality with localstorage data

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I had been working on this project a few months back and kind of forgot about it. Anyway, I am going to try finish it now. My question is this. I have a dynamically created table in which each cell is clickable. On the click you can choose to fill the cell of the table with a different image from an array. This is fine. Using localstorage I can save the table state after clicks have been made to reflect the changes made, but when I exit the page and re-enter the changed images are redrawn but the table is no longer clickable. I am struggling to find a solution. Perhaps you can help? Here is some code:

```
    function makeChart() {
    table = document.createElement('table');
    var taskName = document.getElementById('taskname').value,
    header = document.createElement('th'),
    numDays = document.getElementById('days').value, //columns
    howOften = document.getElementById('times').value, //rows
    row,
    r,
    col,
    c;
    target= numDays*howOften;

var cel = null;
var myImages = new Array();
myImages[0] = "../www/images/test.png";
myImages[1] = "../www/images/test.png";
myImages[2] = "../www/images/test.png";
var my_div = document.createElement("div");
my_div.id = "showPics";
document.body.appendChild(my_div);
var newList = document.createElement("ul");
my_div.appendChild(newList);

if (taskName == '' || numDays == '') {
    alert('Please enter task name and number of days');
}
if (howOften == '') {
    howOften = 1;
}
if (taskName != '' && numDays != '') {


    for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
        var allImages = new Image();
        allImages.src = myImages[i];
        allImages.onclick = function (e) {
            if (sel !== null) {
                sel.src = e.target.src;
                my_div.style.display = 'none';
                sel.onclick = null;
                sel = null;
            }
        };

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(allImages);
        newList.appendChild(li);
    }
    my_div.style.display = 'none';

    header.innerHTML = taskName;
    table.appendChild(header);

    function addImage(col) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "../www/images/imageholder.png";
        col.appendChild(img);
        img.onclick = function () {
            my_div.style.display = 'block';
            sel = img;
        };
    }
    for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
        row = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
            col = row.insertCell(-1);
            addImage(col);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('singleUser').appendChild(table);
    var blankVal = {
            value : ''
          };
          $("#taskname").attr(blankVal);
          $("#days").attr(blankVal);
          $("#times").attr(blankVal);

    document.getElementById('createChart').onclick = null;
    saveData();
    }
    }
function saveData(){
    localStorage.setItem(name, table.innerHTML);
}
function showData(){
var showme = localStorage.getItem(name); 
var newTable = document.createElement('table');
newTable.innerHTML= showme;
newTable.id = "newTable";
var showIt= document.getElementById('holdTable');
showIt.appendChild(newTable);
console.log(showIt); 
};
```

Comment: where does name come from?

Comment: Sorry, name is entered earlier from a form and is used to identify particular user and passed through a button id to identify their particular table. Does that make sense?

Comment: showData() is never called in this snippet. Is it called from somewhere else?

Comment: well "name" is a bad global name to use; ex: name=[1,2,3]; typeof name == "string"; but if it's a string anyway, i guess ittl work; i just avoid name outright...

Comment: Hi Ken, yes showData() is called earlier so that when the user opens their particular page their table and saved data is called. However, it shows but cannot be edited.